# Is there a way to set modal property keyboard=true for all modals within the page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set the value keyboard=true for all modals within a page.  Is there a way to configure that to be set as default or do I need to go to each modal and set it?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-data-attrs  It shows you how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the case is closed and you've rendered your verdict, but I wanna testify:

The accepted answer sets the keyboard option for all the modals that currently exist by going through them one by one<sup>†</sup>.  You can extend objects that have not yet been created, and do so while taking less of a performance hit by just setting the default option:

```js
$.fn.modal.Constructor.DEFAULTS.keyboard = true;
```

### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/HDChy/)

---

<sup>†</sup> - Here is a direct quote from the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-data-attrs):

```js
$('#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false })   // initialized with no keyboard
```

This code *initializes* each modal in the selector `$('#myModal')` and also sets one of the options when doing so.

[**Here's a demo with two modals**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/HDChy/2) - they both will be initialized immediately! It goes through each one, initializes it, and applies the setting.  The question was not asking for a way to initialize the modals that use a setting.  It was asking for a way to default the settings so future initializations wouldn't have to specify it.  In terms of performance, just doing the the lookup in the DOM for `$('.modal')` costs extra that overriding the default does not.

Comment: I agree.  And after testing the version above.  There needs to be more to it.  The previous solution will open the window.

Comment: @OldManProgrammer, That's right! [`$('#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false })`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api) will *initialize* the modal while simultaneously specifying the keyboard setting.

Comment: "The accepted answer sets the keyboard option for all the modals that currently exist by going through them one by one" that is not true, it sets it when any modal is initiated!

Comment: @nolawipetros, [Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/HDChy/2/). I copy and pasted in your code.  Executing it *initializes the modal* right away, instead of just setting a default.  Also, if that's your downvote, I'd appreciate it if you'd reconsider.

Comment: ya I agree with your comment above about the default but that doesn't mean its going through them one by one. The default is set when a modal is constructed either way its the same thing, i believe there is zero performance hit at all!

Answer (score -1):

you can set it via modal options in js using a class that is on all modals

```
 $('.modal').modal({
   keyboard: true
  })
```

like the above, you can also comma delimitate `$('#myModals1, #myModals2').modal...`

Comment: Thanks, must be a DUH moment.